Counting cliques in polynomial time
Let $G$ be a disconnected graph such that every connected component is a $k$-clique, $k \geq 2$. That is, a connected component of $G$ can be a single edge, or a triangle, or a $K_4$ and so on. Is it possible in this specific case to count all cliques in $G$ in polynomial time?

Since every connected component is a clique, you simply need to count the number of connected components, which can be done in $O(n+e)$ time.  Do you want the algorithm to return the size of each connected component?

Right. Yes I do, but I guess I can just check the degree of one of the vertices - thanks!
